# Parse PFFile Long Url

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pffile

I want to send PFFile url in sms using twilio api, but the piffle url string is too long is there any way to shorten the piffle url ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: a url shortening service...

Comment: you can send a get call with your url check this http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=http://scripting.com/

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=https://www.google.com.pk/

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I recommend you shorten the URL using one of the available URL shorteners with APIs. I've always used [Bitly](http://bitly.com) for this. You can check out their API at the [Bitly dev site](http://dev.bitly.com/).

You can shorten a URL with a GET request to:

```
https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&longUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F
```

The example long url there is http://google.com/

The response will look a bit like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "global_hash": "900913", 
    "hash": "ze6poY", 
    "long_url": "http://google.com/", 
    "new_hash": 0, 
    "url": "http://bit.ly/ze6poY"
  }, 
  "status_code": 200, 
  "status_txt": "OK"
}
```

[You can check out the documentation to the shorten endpoint here](http://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_shorten).

Let me know if that helps.